# Wrapping Element with multiple nested transclude

Tags: angularjs, nested

This seems like such a simple thing, but I am just not able to wrap my head around how to do it.

Here is what I want:

```
<my-card>
  <my-profile>
     <my-address>101 Some St.</my-address>
     <my-phone>555-555-5555</my-phone>
     <my-description>I have a great profile</mydescription>
  </my-profile>
  <my-option doclick="Option(1)">Do One</my-option>
  <my-option doclick="Option(2)">Do Two</my-option>
</my-card>
```

That turns into something like this:

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="profile">
      <div class="Address">101 Some St.</div>
      <div class="Phone">555-555-5555</div>
      <div class="Description">I have a great profile.</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What's the question? What does your directive look like?

Comment: Well, that's just the problem, I'm not sure how to format the directives to do this.

Comment: Please make an effort and bring back a more specific question. Google and the Angular docs should get you started.

Comment: more specific, ok if you notice the code above my-card includes a profile that has multiple elements... address phone and description. I don't understand how to code the transclude to position the my-address where the address goes and my-phone where the phone goes.

I can place a single layer of information but the multiples elude me. 

so if my template looks like 
`    <div class="card">


As for google and angular docs, if it was that easy I would have been done by now.

Comment: `<div class="card">
    <div class="profile">
        <div class="Address" ng-transclude></div>
        <div class="Phone" ng-transclude></div>
        <div class="Description" ng-transclude></div>
    </div>
</div>`

if that is my template HOW do I specify that <my-phone> is placed in the proper slot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what your data look like, but you simply use Angular tokens in your directive:

```
<my-card>
  <my-profile>
     <my-address>{{user.address}}</my-address>
     <my-phone>{{user.phone}}</my-phone>
     <my-description>{{user.description}}</mydescription>
  </my-profile>
  <my-option doclick="Option(1)">Do One</my-option>
  <my-option doclick="Option(2)">Do Two</my-option>
</my-card>
```